# javascript sprite animation in a game

Tags: javascript, html, animation, sprite

I am working on a simple animation of a sprite in a little Javascript game, a mosquito that is changing state while flying towards right. These states correspond to two different images in my tile sheet.

So far I have been doing this, but the animation is very irregular:

```
for (var i = 0; i < mosquitos.length; i++) {
  var mosquito = mosquitos[i];

  setInterval (updateAnimation, 500);
  mosquito.update();

  // rest of code non-relevant to animation here...
```

and then, later:

```
function updateAnimation () {
  next();

  function next () {
    mosquito.state = mosquito.FLYINGRIGHT1;
    setTimeout (previous, 500);

    function previous () {
      mosquito.state = mosquito.FLYINGRIGHT;
    }
  }
}
```

The two states are of course FLYINGRIGHT and FLYINGRIGHT1...
problem is that mosquito starts animating very quickly and very irregularly. I would like it to change state, i.e. every half of a second. I tried with different time periods but it is always the same effect.

I can produce a jsfiddle of the whole thing, if what I am missing is not so obvious.

Thank you for any help and insights.

Here's the game in question, from my website:

http://www.retroinvaders.net/laurasworld/src/laurasTriviaLevels.html

Comment: I think a fiddle would be helpful :)

Comment: The problem is that for the entire thing there are a lot of resources to upload, sounds, etc... I'll work on a simplified version, focusing on the animation matter, but it's not easy.

Comment: Hello, I uploaded the game and put the link in the original question. Do let me know what you think...

Comment: Hey, I took a look. It doesn't look too bad in Chrome. Have you made changes that address your issue? Or, is it specific to a certain browser?

Comment: Hello, I can implement some random mosquito animation with what follows:

in LoadHandler function: 
 setInterval (updateAnimation, 300);

in playGame() function:
findWaitTime = function ()
{
 waitTime = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
}
updateAnimation = function ()
{
findWaitTime();
if (waitTime >3)
{
mosquito.state = mosquito.FLYINGRIGHT;
}
else
{
mosquito.state = mosquito.FLYINGRIGHT1;
}
}

It's random, but not that bad. What do you think?

Comment: OH, I got you. You're saying that rather than just flying left/right (as in the fiddle), you actually want some randomness to the movement of the mosquito??

Comment: Sure, a regular animation if possible. Let's say it changes state every second or so. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rethink this part:

```
var mosquito = mosquitos[i];
setInterval (updateAnimation, 500);
```

I suppose you want every new 'updateAnimation' get a different mosquito (mosquitos[0], mosquitos[1] .. mosquitos[i]). But what really happens is something different. Every time you get the same mosquito (mosquitos[i]).
This is because of asynchronous behaviour of setInterval() function.

```
function updateAnimation () {
  next();

  function next() {
           // every time, mosquito is equal to mosquitos[i]
           // and NOT mosquitos[0], then mosquitos[1] ...
           mosquito.state = mosquito.FLYINGRIGHT1;
           setTimeout (previous, 500);

          function previous()
                  {
                       mosquito.state = mosquito.FLYINGRIGHT;

                  }

      }
   }
```

Comment: There is currently just one mosquito actually... I think that the problem is rather focusing on how setInterval and setTimeout behave and interact...and cause a mess if used improperly... perhaps there is an elegant and simpler solution, but right now i am missing it.

Comment: I put a link to the actual game in the original question for your consideration. Thanks.